# Variable outside event function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, global-variables

this variable is undefined outside the function()
i want this variable work outside function() and I want this variable to change every time I choose the selected option
code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var interval_day;
   $('#select_id').change(function(){
      interval_day = $('#select_id').val();
   });
   document.getElementById('etst').innerHTML = interval_day;
<script>
```

html code :

```
 <select id="select_id">
     <option value="1">One</option>
     <option value="2">Two</option>
 </select>
```

please help me for this..

Comment: Why not a global variable `interval_day` ?

Comment: Please describe more clearly. This very annoying question. Define variable globally then you can able to access that.

Comment: I am confused about how to create a global variable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Answer (score 1):

If You want Global Variable then Use Like Below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var  interval_day; ///Define your Global Variable
 $('#select_id').change(function(){
     interval_day = $('#select_id').val(); ////Put Value in Global variable
      });

$(function() {
 $("#pickup").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
     minDate: inverval_day
   });
});
<script>
```

Answer (score 0):

no need to make it global var just get it direct from select value

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
   $("#pickup").datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
      minDate: Number($('#select_id').val())
   });
});
<script>
```

I didn't use same value because it has to be number so you  have to cast it to number `Number($('#select_id').val())` to work with datepicker

Comment: I just pass the same value he used may be he has different values in the select